# Delphi TRestClient send Body as "data-raw"

Tags: delphi, http-post, rest-client, delphi-10.4.2

How to add body parameter to `TRestClient` like in Postman? If body data is defined like below as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` it would be wrong:

```bash
curl -L -X POST 'https://ms2.medapp.ch/rest/lg1/v1/call-medapp' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
-d '..datastring..'
```

How to define `TRestClient` and its body parameter so that it looks like the following example from Postman?

```bash
curl -L -X POST 'https://ms2.medapp.ch/rest/lg1/v1/call-medapp' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-raw '..datastring..'
```

The problem is in the executeion of `TRestClient`: the parameter is interpreted wrongly. Which option do I have to set to send the body as raw?

Comment: You need to set [poDoNotEncode](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/REST.Types.TRESTRequestParameterOption) option on the parameter of kind [pkREQUESTBODY](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/REST.Types.TRESTRequestParameterKind). [ContentType](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/REST.Client.TRESTRequestParameter.ContentType) of that parameter can be either `ctNone` or `ctAPPLICATION_X_WWW_FORM_URLENCODED`.

Comment: @PeterWolf Thanks, but same Result: Instead of HTTP-Status 201 the Response is 200

Comment: You should definitely [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77141184/edit) your question and add some relevant code.